# Cannot boot anymore, power supply broken?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

My desktop computer is not able to boot anymore. Currently I have breadboarded my computer taking everything out of the case so the motherboard is only connected with:

500W power supply, connected with 2x4 12V for CPU and 2x12 Main Power
2x 4GB Ram
i5 Processor + Fan
When I switch on, the CPU fan starts to spin and the phase leds on the motherboard appear for a short time and then they disappear which I think is normal.

If I add

Graphic card 512mb Radeoon
OR

2x more 4GB RAM
The CPU fan spins but the phase leds on the motherboard do not disappear. If I plug the graphic card nothing appears on the screen.

My assumption is that the Power Supply does not handle more hardware parts because it is not working properly.

The problem is I dont have any spare parts to test this. Based on the information can I assume the Power Supply is broken?

Thanks!

Comment: Some problem history would help. Did you do anything to it between when it did boot and when it doesn't boot? Did something happen?

Comment: Do you still get the BIOS beeps, or nothing at all?

Comment: I sent my computer with mail and when I received it the CPU fan had fallen off and my graphic card as well so they where loose in the case :s

Comment: Could the reason be that I need to add new thermal paste to the CPU before attaching the CPU fan? Regarding the beep I hear only one long + 2 short beeps in the beginning (I have only one 2GB RAM installed no graphic card)

Comment: What motherboard model/vendor do you have? Since there is POST check failure it's highly unlikely that it's power supply fault